# Device Orientation Carry Over

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen-orientation

I'm using Unity 3D to create a simple menu. I couldn't get ancors so instead, I've used two Canvas with different layouts according to Landscape and Portrait.

This works perfect for me.
**BUT.**

I have to properly set the device in that orientation for it to properly register.

> **To explain better:** I've put Landscape values as default in `Start()`
>   and in `Update()` I have the `checkandchanger()` which checks the
>   orientation and changes it to the appropriate layout.
>
> So now, if I have my device on Portrait and I change scenes, and if my
>   device isn't perfectly in that orientation (straight up) it loads the
>   Landscape.

**Hence, coming to my question, is it possible to send orientation of the previous scene to the next scene?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Create an empty gameobject named "**OrientationManger**". Attach a simple script to it and make sure that this script doesn't destroy when loading the next scene. This script will have public functions that **sets** the current orientation or **reads** the last orientation from the previous scene.

You can then reference those values from both scene 1 and scene 2.

To **prevent** this "OrientationManger" gameobject and the script attached to it from **destroying** when **loading** the **next scene**, use:

use

```
void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
```

EDIT: 
This is what the OrientationManager should look like. You can choose any method of doing it.

```
public class OrientationManger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private OrientationType currentOrientation; ///////////////Method 1 (ENUM)
    int orientationType = 1; ///////////////Method 2 (OR use Integer 1,2)

    //Makes sure there is only once instance running
    void Awake ()
    {
        // singleton
        if (FindObjectsOfType (typeof(OrientationManger)).Length > 1) {
            Debug.Log ("OrientationManger already exist");
            DestroyImmediate (gameObject); //Destroy this gameobject because it already exist
        } else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject); //Wont destroy when loading another level/scene
        }
    }

    ///////////////Method 1 Set (ENUM)
    public void setOrientation (OrientationType orientType)
    {
        currentOrientation = orientType;
    }

    ///////////////Method 1 Get (ENUM)
    public OrientationType getOrientation ()
    {
        return currentOrientation;
    }

    ///////////////Method 2 Set (OR use Integer 1,2)
    public void setOrientation2 (int orientType)
    {
        if (orientType == 1) {
            orientationType = orientType;
        } else if (orientType == 2) {
            orientationType = orientType;
        }
    }

    ///////////////Method 2 Get (OR use Integer 1,2)
    public int getOrientation2 ()
    {
        if (orientationType == 1 || orientationType == 2) {
            return orientationType;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}

///////////////Method 1 (ENUM)
public enum OrientationType
{
    UKNOWN,
    Portrait,
    Landscape
}
;
```

Comment: Okay, I had thought of this. But let's say I follow your answer. What would be the return type of the public function? And how would I check the orientation before the scene loads? `Start()` usually loads along with the scene, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: you can just make it return int. 1 as Portrait  and 2 as Landscape. You can even use enum to do this. Either way, it doesn't matter how you do it.

Comment: Awesome. DIdn't strike me. Will check it out and mark as answer/reply with the problem soon. Thanks.

Comment: I modified the code with both methods of how you can do this. Use which ever one you like best. enum or int...